# Issue setting breakpoint in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project in release mode. I cannot convert it to debug mode for some reason.

When I'm debugging and I try to put a break point on function A, I cannot put it there - The breakpoint moves itself to function B which is exactly the same in content (i.e. function A and funciton B are exactly same just have different names).

I do understand that it must have optimized out the code, but I am using an option called as `/od` which means it should have suppressed code movement.

How can I put a breakpoints on function A?

Comment: you may put any useless cod line in function A like for example int x=5+5; and put the breakpoints there. It is not a solution but just something came in my mind

Comment: Not sure what's actually going on there, so I'll keep this a comment: You can try to put a `#pragma auto_inline(off)` and a `#pragma optimize( "dy", on )` right before the function you want to be able to step in. This should a) result in different instructions for the two functions and b) keep the function as such instead of (possibly) inlining it. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah08w5c3.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

Comment: @Humam Helfawi thats did it for me .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the optimization options.
- Right-click on the project->properties.
- Configuration Properties
- C/C++
- Optimization
- Optimization-> Select Disabled(/Od)
This should avoid that the compiler remove code.
But, still, in release mode you are not sure if the displayed data is correct.

Comment: Be sure also to check that in general section you have the Whole Program Optimization disabled, just in case.